# Unexpected Token

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following function:

```
   function LogEvent(ID,description) {
            var userName = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_username').value;
            var download_link = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_url_download').value;


             $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "Logger.aspx",
                        data: { person: userName, item: ID, desc: description },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: {  
                               $.fileDownload(download_link);
                            }                                
                     });

    }
```

Now I get an error around the `$.fileDownload(download_link);` line.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

If I remove the entire success section it works fine, if I replace the $.file... with alert('hi'); I get a similar error.

Note, the filedownload function is the jquery.download plugin, but I know the issue is more general as noted when using alert - which also doesn't work.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
success: function() {
    $.fileDownload(download_link);
}
```

As it is, the parser is probably assuming

```
{
    $.fileDownload(download_link);
}
```

is an object, which doesn't make sense since objects should be key-value pairs.

Comment: Also, thank you for the explanation of why mine wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

You've forgotten the `function()` part of the callback function, or you're mixing object and function notations.

```
success: function() {  
    $.fileDownload(download_link);
}
```